# 2Gen Google Cloud Functions deploy as module

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, es6-modules

I'm trying to deploy a 2 Gen Google Cloud Function (trigger event type) as a module since I need to use import statement.

The problem is that GCP cannot find an entry point
How should I modify following code?

index.js

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

// Register a CloudEvent callback with the Functions Framework that will
// be executed when the Pub/Sub trigger topic receives a message.
functions.cloudEvent('printPDFFromHTMLtest2', cloudEvent => {
  // The Pub/Sub message is passed as the CloudEvent's data payload.
  const base64name = cloudEvent.data.message.data;

  const name = base64name
    ? Buffer.from(base64name, 'base64').toString()
    : 'World';

  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Your question should provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) with instructions that we can follow, along with your specific observations about what doesn't work the way you expect.  Please edit the question with these details.

Comment: Following Doug's suggestion I edited my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a solution.

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "type":"module"
}
```

index.js

```
import functions from '@google-cloud/functions-framework';

export const printPDFFromHTMLtest2 = functions.cloudEvent('printPDFFromHTMLtest2', cloudEvent => {
  // The Pub/Sub message is passed as the CloudEvent's data payload.
  const base64name = cloudEvent.data.message.data;

  const name = base64name
    ? Buffer.from(base64name, 'base64').toString()
    : 'World';

  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
});
```